# How can I emit an array of objects using socket.io and cryptojs with sql server results?

Tags: node.js, sql-server, socket.io, cryptojs

I'm trying to emit an array using Socket.io, but I'm getting a error. The code and error is below. I'm new to using WebSockets, so what can I do to emit this properly?

```
var conn = new sql.ConnectionPool(dbConfig);
var req = new sql.Request(conn);
 conn.connect(function(err){
  if(err){
    console.log("err");
    return;
  }
  console.log('conectou')
  let vend = 'AUGUSTO'
  req.query(`select * from aca_visitas where cd_vend = '${vend}' and 
     dt_visita >= '2019-03-01'`, 
  function(err, array){

    if(err)
    {
      console.log("err db");
    }
    else{
      let resultado = array.recordset
      console.log(resultado)
      var ciphertext = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(JSON.stringify(resultado), 
          'secret key 123');
      io.emit("Data-from-server",ciphertext);
}
```

The error:

```
C:\Trabalho\Projetos\MobSupervisor\TargetMobSupervisor\Prototipo\Retaguarda\node_modules\has-binary2\index.js:30
function hasBinary (obj) {
                   ^

RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

Answer (score 0):

To emit and encrypt an Array or Object, you should first do a serialization, you could do that with (`JSON.stringify`) like you done in your code, and finnaly you need to put a `.toString()` method to emit a "plain text" (is a plain text now, because of serialization).

Your code should be:

```
var ciphertext = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(JSON.stringify(resultado), 'secret key 123').toString();
io.emit("Data-from-server",ciphertext);
```

Crypto-js DOC: https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-js